# Simple way to only return the ID of child objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API. I included the controller and the object that I would like to return. The problem is, this object can have a lot of children that in turn can have a lot of children. In order to keep things manageable I would like to only return the Id's of the children.

The only solution I can come up with is to make an 'inbetween' object. This object can populate / be populated from and to the database object. But I can imagine that this gets quite cumbersome when the API grows. Also its quite prone to errors when fields get added but forgotten to populate.

Is it possible to make something like an attribute that ensures only the Id of the child gets returned?

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ProjectItemsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetById")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<MyItem>> GetById(int id)
    {
        MyItem? item = await _context.FindAsync<MyItem>(id);

        if (item == null)
            return NotFound();

        return Ok(item);
    }
}

public class ProjectItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } = "";
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public virtual User? CreatedByUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectItem> Children { get; } = new List<ProjectItem>();
    public virtual ProjectItem? Parent { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**: to avoid confusion I would like this as response

GetById/1

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "string",
  "created": "2023-09-20T19:51:04.524Z",
  "createdByUser": {
    "id": 0,
    "keycloakId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
    "userName": "string",
    "email": "string"
  },
  "children": [
    { "id": 2 } ,
    { "id": 3 }
  ],
  "parent": { "id": 4 }
}
```

Comment: Only properties of the class that are public get serialized.  So removing public all properties (except Id) will only return Id.  The controller serializes the class and put results into the body of the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "in-between" object is commonly referred to as a [DTO (Data Transfer Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5) and honestly it is the best solution to this type of scenario. Data storage and data transport are two separate concerns. Entities should be concerned solely with data storage/representation, while DTOs are concerned with data transport. There are mapping solutions out there like [Automapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html), [Mapperly](https://mapperly.riok.app/docs/getting-started/installation/), and [Mapster](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster) which support projection through EF's `IQueryable` implementation, or you can use tried & true `Select()`.  Refer to Automapper's `ProjectTo<T>()` as an example.

By defining DTOs you can create more efficient transport objects that just contain the information the consumers need, avoiding things like cyclic references, and providing things like specific formatting for transport. (I.e. DateTime formatting to `string`, etc.)

One obstacle to trying to define cut-down entities for a `DbContext`/`DbSet` to provide is that EF only supports one entity definition per table, per `DbContext`. This would mean that an API returning these cut-down summary entities would need to use a different `DbContext` instance than code that wants to be able to work with the entire object graph. This is an approach I used to use with earlier EF and [NHibernate](https://nhibernate.info/) (which does support multiple definitions per table) but projection to purpose build view models / DTOs negates the need for this complexity and makes these concerns a lot easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your permanent functionality, where you only return the ID of the children record, create a corresponding models

```cs
public class ProjectItemLimited
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectItemLimited> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual ProjectItemLimited? Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And for the routes where you need all data, used different models/db context.

And in case I misunderstood, and what you really need is limited exposure for the API data... in this case you can keep the original model for the DB context and create this limited model, and use a tool like AutoMapper to hydrate your model for the JSON response.

**For your edit**: There are few ways of doing it. Use separate data and serialization models with a mapping hydration tool. Use custom model binder/serializer.